# Building Dockerfile error: no such file or directory, open '/rc-user-service/package.json'

Tags: node.js, express, dockerfile, package.json

I'm trying to write a dockerfile for my express server that runs at /rc-user-service. I think i'm creating a directory called /rc-user-service, making it the working directory, copying in all files (I have tried both including and not including the COPY package*.json ./), installing it, exposing it's port, then running it. I get this Error after RUN npm install:

```
  npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/rc-user-service/package.json'
  npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
  npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/rc-user-service/package.json'
  npm WARN rc-user-service No description
  npm WARN rc-user-service No repository field.
  npm WARN rc-user-service No README data
  npm WARN rc-user-service No license field.
```

I have tried putting the Dockefile both inside the server and in a directory with the server. In the later I get this error under COPY package*.json: COPY failed: no source files were specified.

Dockerfile:

```
  FROM node:12.18
  RUN mkdir -p /rc-user-service
  WORKDIR /rc-user-service
  COPY package*.json ./
  COPY . .
  RUN npm install
  EXPOSE 3003
  CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. If I put the Dockerfile in a directory with the server (not in the server) when I called:

```
COPY package*.json ./
```

it was looking for it in the directory with the Dockerfile, not the server itself. So:

```
COPY server/package*.json ./
COPY server/. .
```

built with no issues and when I ran the image the server started.